# Link two columns and merge them if possible

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table. It has two columns. First with ID and second with a value.
In first column the same ID are repeated on couple of rows, but the values for it are different.

My goal is to merge those ID's into one row and have the second column (the values must be merged to and separated by commas)

Here you can see what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? A combination of UNIQUE in one column and TEXTJOIN + FILTER in the next could do if using Office365

Comment: *Is this possible?* Yes, it is. Depending on your version of Excel, it may be easiest with formulas, VBA and/or Power Query.

Comment: Take a look at [Combine Excel Cells Into 1 Cell Based On Date In Next Column](https://superuser.com/questions/1656304/combine-excel-cells-into-1-cell-based-on-date-in-next-column)

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, grammatically/reword to be clear please-  my main issue is what you actually mean to say/relay re: the following "In first column same ID is reapeted on couple of rows but the values for it are different."  There is also a spelling error re: 'repeated' - make use of the auto-spell checker which shows spelling errors using a red squiggly line (right clicking on such words often presents a context menu from which you can select an appropriate word with the correct spelling)...

Answer (score 0):

### ♣ SOLVED  (with demo excel sheet)♣

Pre-requisite: Office 365.

---

**Functions**

Couple of simple formula, no helpers required/necessary (refer to screenshot below for referee

1] list of unique items from first column: unique:

```
= UNIQUE(A1:A35)
```

2] concatenated values in 2nd column - use filter like so:

```
= TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,FILTER($B$1:$B$35,$A$1:$A$35=E1))
```

Get your copy of the demo used in screenshots from [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j961czzYrYo_UjRUpG?e=nX7VF8)

---

**Screenshots for reference:**

[image: Unique values from 1st column]

[image: Concatenated values from second column]

Answer (score -1):

It can be done with some helper columns using any excel version and without having to rely on VBA;

[image: Screenshot]

The formulas are as follows for each column (copy the formula in the cell and drag it down):

Cell `D2`: `=IF(A2=A3,"",A2)`

Cell `E2`: `=IF(A2=A1,CONCATENATE(E1,",",B2),B2)`

Cell `F2`: `=IF(D2="",F1,F1+1)`

Cell `H2`: `=H1+1`

Result on Cell `I2`: `=INDEX(D$2:D$11,MATCH($H2,$F$2:$F$11,0))`

Result on Cell `J2`: `=INDEX(E$2:E$11,MATCH($H2,$F$2:$F$11,0))`

Comment: I don't believe helpers are the best / most robust way - additional unnecessary complexity that will soon prove tricky to administer once the lists become long.  etc.

Comment: @James, Textjoin() is not available for all Excel Versions, so your answer may not be applicable to his case.  While Helpers add one layer of complexity, in this case formulas can be dragged down without much of a hassle, and keep the spreadsheet clean and simple. Last, this answer resolves the issue so I don't understand your negative vote here.

Comment: Revised soln. accordingly.  My view - actually think model dimension/reduction through more robust yet not overly complex formula / functions are/can be better.  E.g. a compact solution without side-helpers can reduce model complexity (if you think about a large spreadsheet / table, lot's of sheets, having helpers scattered about can be quite cumbersome - not to mention set up time/audit trail etc.).  Note: OP was asked what version but did not reply.  Not sure viable to always assume no Office 365 unless specifically requested as part of challenge.  No mention by OP in this case.

Comment: . Question doesn’t mention if it’s for a ver large table. Day to day excel sheets can live with helper columns, specially if they are well formatted and follow data structure.